# is there a way to cancel cloud foundry deployments for an app

Tags: cloud-foundry

We cannot restage our app on cloud foundry as it says a deployment is in progress, we believe this is a "stuck" build
Is there a way to clear all cloud foundry deployments for an app?
Thanks

Comment: There may be other options, but the top thing that comes to mind is that you can either a.) delete the app and repush it or b.) push the app under a new name. If your app is presently down, there's no difference. If your app is up, you can use option b.) then remap routes to cut traffic over seamlessly.